# ldap scheme for email aliases

Tags: email, ldap, alias

Does anyone know what scheme to use when setting up email aliases in LDAP? I could use anything, but it seems kind of abusive to use "title" for example as the email alias. extensibleObject may be the correct thing to use, but it seems wrong.

Comment: What email software is to be used?

Comment: postfix . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `misc.schema` (or `misc.ldif`), usually included with `OpenLDAP`.
It contains the schema definitions for the following attributetypes and objectClasses:

- `mailLocalAddress`
- `mailHost`
- `mailRoutingAddress`
- `inetLocalMailRecipient`
- `rfc822MailMember`
- `nisMailAlias`

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: Yup, that was just what I needed. All set with postfix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at nisMailAlias.